# DRF serializer is_valid() == True, but .save() not persisting model object

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

My list, retrieve, and destroy actions work as expected.

**HTTP Response = 201 'created'**

```
"POST /api/atoms/?uid=04d38ad99b2a4353a18438c651eac5ab&created_at=2019-05-12T22:30:04.725089Z&updated_at=2019-05-12T22:30:07.053148Z&charge=1&mass=2 HTTP/1.1" 201 152
```

**Within ViewSet**

```
class AtomViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = AtomSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        # True

        serializer.save()
        # self.perform_create(serializer) # doesn't work
        # self.node.save() # doesn't work
        # headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,) # headers=headers
```

Here is what I get when I run `serializer.save()`

```
<Atom: {'uid': '04d38ad99b2a4353a18438c651eac5qq', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 12, 22, 30, 4, 725089, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 12, 22, 30, 7, 53148, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'charge': 0.0, 'mass': 1.0}>
```

Despite that encouraging output of save, the resource strangely does not get saved to the database.

I'm using ViewSets and a custom serializer against a non-model model.
`AttributeError: 'AtomViewSet' object has no attribute 'perform_create'`

**Serializer**

```
class AtomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    uid = serializers.CharField()
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = serializers.DateTimeField()

    charge = serializers.FloatField()
    mass = serializers.FloatField()


    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Atom(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for field, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, field, value)
        return instance
```

I'm looking at my serializer now. Not sure what the create and update are supposed to contain

> http://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.serializers/Serializer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `AtomSerializer` you are not actually saving the object, just creating or modifying an instance of it in memory, use `save()` to persist the instance to the db.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    atom = Atom(**validated_data)
    atom.save()
    # Alternative you could use atom = Atom.objects.create(**validated_data)
    return atom
```

Likewise for your update method, you need to save the object after modifying it.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    for field, value in validated_data.items():
        setattr(instance, field, value)
    instance.save() # <-- saving the instance after setattr
    return instance
```

Comment: Thank you! I was about to manually instantiate the model Atom() and set every key value haha. It's weird how the serializer create, save, and perform_create are all related.